# Using data from a table and foreign key table in single query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

hard to explain from title, hopefully this description helps explain the situation. I have a music app where a user can create a playlist. So I set up two tables.

One called `Playlists` (columns: PlaylistID, PlaylistName, CreatorID) and another called `PlaylistSongs` (columns: PlaylistSongID, PlaylistID, and SongID). I have a foreign key connection between the PlaylistID columns.

I want to display a list of playlists on the home page, each one looks like this:
[image]

I can pull the playlist name from `Playlist` table and display properly....easy. The issue I am having is figuring out how to display the metadata such as the artists (Sasha Sloan ODESZA etc) which I can obtain from the SongID from the `PlaylistSongs` table which is connected by foreign key.

Here's what I have right now:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Playlists()
{
    var model = new HomePlaylistViewModel();
    model.Playlists = EntityDataAccess.GetFeaturedPlaylistsByCount(6);

    return View(model);
}
```

Model:

```
public class HomePlaylistViewModel
{
    public List<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
    public List<PlaylistSong> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="playlists-container">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Playlists)
            {
                <div class="playlist-album">
                    <div class="album-grad"></div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h1>
                            @item.PlaylistName
                        </h1>

                        <div class="playlist-desc-container">
                                <h4 class="playlist-desc">Featuring: INSERT ARTIST NAMES HERE</h4>
                                <h4 class="playlist-creator"> Songs &#8226; Curated by
                           </h4>
                        </div>

                        <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/6d669906-60df-4f26-bf80-f11eef3bd019/-/format/jpeg/-/quality/lightest/" class="playlist-album-art">
                    </a>
                    <button class="ui button playlist-listen">LISTEN</button>
                    <button class="ui button playlist-collect"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></button>
                </div>
            }
```

Playlist.cs

```
public partial class Playlist
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Playlist()
    {
        this.PlaylistSongs = new HashSet<PlaylistSong>();
    }

    public int PlaylistID { get; set; }
    public string PlaylistName { get; set; }
    public int CreatorID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlaylistSong> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
}
```

EntityDataAccess.cs

```
public static List<Playlist> GetFeaturedPlaylistsByCount(int count)
        {
            using (var Context = GetContext())
            {
                return Context.Playlists.Take(count).ToList();
            }
        }
```

So I essentially have a model with this `Playlist` info:

- PlaylistID
- PlaylistName
- CreatorID

I need to use each unique `PlaylistID` to access the songs in the `PlaylistSongs` table that have that `PlaylistID`so I can display on screen. Does that make sense?

**EDIT:** Added call to context and corresponding class

```
public static UnearthEntities GetContext()
        {
            var context = new UnearthEntities();
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return context;
        }
```

Unearth Entities:

```
public partial class UnearthEntities : DbContext
    {
        public UnearthEntities()
            : base("name=UnearthEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AccountInfo> AccountInfoes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AlbumTag> AlbumTags { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DownloadHistory> DownloadHistories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Spotlight> Spotlights { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FeaturedAlbum> FeaturedAlbums { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Key> Keys { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SongPlayDaily> SongPlayDailies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PlaylistSong> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Microsoft's article:  [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Assuming your data context is correct, use the `Include` to bring in the related data, like:

```
return Context.Playlists.Include("PlaylistSongs").Take(count).ToList();
```

BTW:  For clarity, I would rename some of your fields.  For example, primary key (PK) field names need not be prefixed with the name of the table.  It gets confusing.  Just name your PK field "Id".  When referring to a key field from within a related table, then use the table name.  For example, to make a one-to-many relationship between Playlists, and PlaylistSongs, a field named PlaylistId would exist in the table PlaylistSongs.

Regarding the building of a model, take a look at Microsoft's documents [Creating a Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) and [Foreign Key Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints).  The first provides a link to github repo of sample code.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. I've been trying to wrap my head around that same article today. I've added and removed that `Include` many times. This time out of curiosity (with it added) I went to my html and added `@item.PlaylistSongs.Count` to see if it's even reading values and my html is blank. This would mean my data context is messed up?

Comment: Post your data context.  You make a call to GetContext() so let us see the code responsible for returning this.

Comment: added an edit to original question, was that what you wanted to check?

Comment: I have updated answer to include other articles that discuss how to define/create a model.

Comment: I believe so.  If you want a conclusive resolve, upload your solution to github and update your answer with a link to the repo.  Then we can go clone this and take a look.  It is the only way to replicate your environment.  The solution needs to be complete and deploy code-first migration in order to replicate the schema,  As well, include some "seed" data in order to have a complete scenario with data.